# How do I determine what version of Silverlight an assembly is compiled against?

Tags: .net, silverlight, assemblies

Given a assembly how do I determine (in code) what version of Silverlight that assembly is compiled against?

So I want a method that does this

```
public static decimal GetSilverlightVersion(string assemblyPath)
{
   Magic goes here
}
```

and it should return 2.0, 3.0 or 4.0

Note: the executing code is .net 4 not Silverlight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler embeds the [TargetFramework] attribute into the assembly.  You can read it back at runtime with reflection.  Some sample code:

```
        var asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var attr = asm.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute), false)
            as System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute[];
        if (attr.Length > 0) {
            label1.Content = attr[0].FrameworkDisplayName;
        }
```

Displayed value on my machine: "Silverlight 4".

Comment: I have no clue what "targeted file" means, only assemblies have a dependency on a Silverlight version.  A file can be anything.  There are additional Assembly class methods that let you pick an assembly, choose one that you care about.

Comment: Hans. Sorry. I actually tried to undo my downvote but i left it too long. It looks like your solution will work. I just need to confirm.